# useradd not encrypting passwords in /etc/shadow

Tags: centos, password, ftp, useradd, shadow

I stumbled accross this problem when trying to create new FTP users for vsftpd.
Upon creating a new user with the following command and attempting login with FileZilla, I would get an "incorrect password" error.

```
useradd f -p pass -d /home/f -s /bin/false
```

After doing this, */etc/shadow* contains

```
f:pass:1111:0:99:2:::
```

Once I run the following command and provide the same pass *pass*

```
passwd f
```

*/etc/shadow* contains

```
f:$1$U1c5vVwg$x5TVDDDmhi0a7RWFer6Jn1:1111:0:99:2:::
```

It appears that encryption happens when I run **passwd**, but doesn't upon **useradd**

Importantly after doing this, I am able to login to FTP with the exact same credentials.

I am using CentOS 5.11, vsftpd for FTP, and FileZilla for FTP Access

*/var/log/secure* contains:

```
Dec 17 useradd[644]: new group: name=f, GID=511
Dec 17 useradd[644]: new user: name=f, UID=511, GID=511, home=/home/f, shell=/bin/false
```

**Why does it not work when I pass `-p pass` to useradd?** What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: I don't see a question there? -  Such things are managed through PAM and typically logged in `/var/log/secure`

Comment: @HBruijn I have updated my answer to show what is written to */var/log/secure*

Comment: Really? +12 for a question that is explicitly answered by the relevant man page?

Comment: Note that [in a password hash, `$1$` indicates MD5 is used](http://superuser.com/a/622895/53590). MD5, while not outright *terrible* for passwords, is rather on the weak side these days. It's an entirely separate question, but I would absolutely urge you to consider migrating to a stronger hash function.

Comment: Side note: passwords in `/etc/shadow` are not encrypted but hashed

Comment: You can use `adduser` instead, if your distro has it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is working as intended. If you want to set a password using the `useradd` command, you are supposed to give a hashed version of the password to `useradd`.

The string `pass` does satisfy the format criteria for the hashed password field in `/etc/shadow`, but no actual password hashes to that string. The result is that for all intents and purposes, that account will behave as having a password, but any password you try to use to access it will be rejected as not being the correct password.

See `man useradd` or the [useradd documentation](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/useradd.htm):

> `-p`, `--password` *PASSWORD*
>
> The encrypted password, as returned by [crypt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html). The default is
>   to disable the password.
>
> Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or
>   encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
>
> You should make sure the password respects the system's password
>   policy.

Answer (score 32):

`man`[useradd](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/useradd.htm):

```
   -p, --password PASSWORD
       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to
       disable the password.
```

You are supposed to pass a hashed password to it.
Not a plaintext password.

Answer (score 16):

`useradd` expects you to pass it the hash of the password, not the password itself.  You can use the following variation on your command to provide a hashed password to the `useradd` command:

```
useradd f -p "$(mkpasswd --method=sha-512 'pass')" -d /home/f -s /bin/false
```

To find out the methods available, use:

```
mkpasswd --method=help
```

In order to avoid passing the password on the command line, put the password in a file (using an editor and not using `echo` or similar) and do this:

```
useradd f -p "$(mkpasswd --method=sha-512 --password-fd=0 < filename)" -d /home/f -s /bin/false
```

This will pass the hashed password on the command line, but not the plaintext one.

`mkpasswd` comes with the `expect` package.

Comment: Don't use MD5! Use SHA-2

Comment: **Do** note that this temporarily exposes the password through the various kernel interfaces (any process is allowed to read the command line of any other process) and may result in it being saved in plain text to disk through $HISTORY or similar mechanisms.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: A **very** good point. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Of course, you're still storing the plain text password on disk. At least, this gives the sysadmin a choice. Maybe at this point we're better off just using a dummy password at first and immediately running `passwd` to change it to something else......

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: The file can have 600 permission which will make it readable only to the owner of the file. And when you're finished, `rm` the file. This is much more secure than have the password show up in the output of `ps`.

Comment: Absolutely Dennis, it's much better, but the password still ends up on the disk in plain text. In some situations and under certain threat models, that can be a real problem. It doesn't *have* to be.