# Can't login via IMAP after creating user via useradd command

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to create a new user (that can access email) with useradd. My command is

```
useradd --shell /bin/bash --create-home --password <password> <username>
```

However, I cannot login to email. When I use `adduser` to create an account, I can login to the mail just fine.

I am creating a home directory because my `dovecot.conf` has `mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u`

my `mail.err` file just has this repeated

```
Feb 21 15:52:46 server dovecot: auth-worker(3609): Error: pam(test,<myip>): 
pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure
```

How can I connect to the email (imap) with useradd? (or at least with one line)

Comment: What's OS and its version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message:

```
Feb 21 15:52:46 server dovecot: auth-worker(3609): Error: pam(test,<myip>): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure
```

can be caused by several reasons such as:

- User didn't exist
- Incorrect password

Based on above `useradd` command

```
useradd --shell /bin/bash --create-home --password <password> <username>
```

I suspect that you fall to the following mistake: [useradd not encrypting passwords in /etc/shadow](https://serverfault.com/q/653203/218590). Above command will put the **plaintext password** into `/etc/shadow`. And because PAM expects that /etc/shadow has encrypted password and yet you have plaintext password, the authentication will fail.